# escape 'value' in OO PHP

Tags: php, soap

I was not sure how to title this question feel free to re-word it...

I am dealing with a SOAP response that has an object by the name of 'value'(I know... not smart it is third party so I cannot change it!)

```
$application = $result->return[$i]->extendedist[12]->value->displayValue;


[value] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [displayValue] =>
                        [internal] =>
                        [id] =>
                    )
```

As you can see this is a problem because `PHP` wants to use its built in value function. How can I escape this and use the value object from the response?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `return`?

Comment: updated to show it is not return

Comment: Which is this quaint "built in value function" of which you speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result->{'return'}
```

Should work.

Depending on how you read the response you could decode it into an array instead and use

```
$result['return']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access an object property such as `$foo->value` as `$foo->{'value'}` as well.